# how to share iOS game screen in real time?

Tags: ios, cocoa, screen, 2d, share

I created a simple game on iPhone. I want to show my play in real time to my friend's iPhone through network.

- Do you know any open source to implement the part?
- Or, can you let me know which part I should study to implement it? open gl? cocoa 2d?

thank you.

Comment: guess I need to learn bitmap image context.. right?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no such a think as screen sharing features on iOS and even if there were they would probably be prohibited by Apple. The only screen sharing feature there is is Air Play, which is available for developers to use, but this sharing is only done through an Apple TV. Check out this documents and see, however: [Multiple Display Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [Air Play Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045).

If you want to make a multiplayer game (either when players play simultaniusly or a turn-based game) you should use the Game Center APIs instead of sharing a screen directly. Please check the [Game Center Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: thank you for answer. what if it can be done in opengl (or cocoa2d?) layer, not kernel level? there's no need for apple to ban it, i think.

Comment: As I said, even if there was I way to do it which I'm not aware of, I'm not sure Apple will approve this usage. If you want to make a turn-bases or multiplayer game  you should use the Game Center APIs to accomplish this. I'm updating my answer to give you a link to the documentation. Anyway, you might want to check the Apple Apps Review Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html